# CDI doesn't work in a simple adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cdi, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters, open-liberty

I've added the CDI feature to the **server.xml** file`<feature>cdi-1.2</feature>`.

My maven module contains the **beans.xml** inside the `<module_name>/src/main/resources/META-INF` folder.

This is the beans.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

But when I use the `@Inject` annotation it doesn't work, my bean is always `null`.

**Code:**

```
package ch.webapp.presentation;

...

@Path("/test/")
public class MyController {
    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @GET
    @Path("/foo/{count}")
    @OAuthSecurity(scope = "login")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response news(@PathParam("count") int count) {
        return Response
                .ok(myService.getBar(count))
                .build();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

That's my bean

```
package ch.webapp.service;

...

@RequestScoped
public class MyService {
    public String getBar(int count) {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

I initialize jax-rs by extended the `MFPJAXRSApplication` class

```
package ch.webapp;

...

public class AccountApplication extends MFPJAXRSApplication {
    @Override
    protected void init() throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    protected void destroy() throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPackageToScan() {
        return getClass().getPackage().getName();
    }
}
```

**Environment details:**

```
Launching mfp (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.8/wlp-1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_172-b11 (en_CH)

Console Product version: 8.0.0.00-20180717-175523
```

What's wrong?

Comment: is `MyService` defined as a CDI bean or have an explicit producer (`@Produces`) method?

Comment: (to define `MyService` as a CDI bean you simply put `@ApplicationScoped` or `@RequestScoped` on the `MyService` class)

Comment: The `MyService` class is annotated with `@Stateless`

Comment: Are you sure that CDI is activated for JAX-RS resources? It may need some additional config (I cannot tell, since I do not know Websphere). Is `MyService` `@Stateless`, or `@RequestScoped`? There is not much point in being both! Is it located in the same jar as `MyController`? If not, is there a beans.xml in the jar containing `MyService`? Also make sure `@RequestScoped` is `javax.enterprize.context` and not the one under `javax.faces.bean`!

Comment: Do you access the resource in the usual way directly via an http client?  I want to be certain you aren't constructing MyController yourself.

Comment: @covener yes, I invoke the rest endpoint from web, postman or react native app.

Comment: How do you initialize jax-rs? Do you have an implementation of Application? With servlet in web.xml?

Comment: @k5_ I updated the question with more details. In my project I've `beans.xml` under the `META-INF` folder and `web.xml` under the `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Have you enabled the [cdi-1.2 feature](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_cdi_config.html) in server.xml?

Comment: Please provide Websphere version.

Comment: @AsSiDe Websphere libery 8

Launching mfp (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.8/wlp-1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_172-b11 (en_CH)
Console Product version: 8.0.0.00-20180717-175523

Comment: 1. In which packages your AccountApplication and MyService are defined? 2. What it seems to me is your MyService is in the different module and you're using this maven module as a dependency in another module i.e. your war packaging module or if I'm wrong then AccountApplication and MyService are in the same module and this is your *.war module? Please confirm. 3. FQCN (ie. with package name) of MyController and AccountApplication classes? Please add mentioned details in the original question, I'll form my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AsSiDe MyService is in the same module of the Controller class.

Comment: @AsSiDe I updated my question with the package info.

Comment: Any reason why your beans.xml is still CDI v1.1 and not v1.2 or v2.0?

Answer (score 1):

First it seems that websphere jax-rs implementation does not integrate jax-rs resources automatically unless you annotate them appropriately.

Put the jax-rs in a CDI managed context by annotating it appropriately

```
@Path("/test/")
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
public class MyController {

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @GET
    @Path("/foo/{count}")
    @OAuthSecurity(scope = "login")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response news(@PathParam("count") int count) {
        return Response
                .ok(myService.getBar(count))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Also be sure that the annotation used for your service is 
`@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the inputs provided by you please go through the below checklist.

1. Your services and controllers are in the same module and its packaging type is war, So you must place your `beans.xml` in this path `src/main/resources/WEB-INF/beans.xml`. (If this is Java EE 7 application then beans.xml is optional.
2. In your AccountApplication class try hardcoding the package name to `ch.webapp.presentation`

   @Override
       protected String getPackageToScan() {
           return "ch.webapp.presentation";
       }

This is just to check Behaviour of MFPJAXRSApplication.getPackageToScan() method whether it is scanning the specified package only or its child packages too.

3. Except these, everything seems fine to me. If this still doesn't work add complete application startup logs so that community can find the root cause of it.

Answer (score -2):

This is classical mistake. CDI works for **managed** beans (for instance EJB's and servlets). If you want to enable it on your JAXRS bean, you have to make it "managed", that is annotate MyController as (**for instance**) `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` or as a `javax.ejb.Stateless`.

Also beware that in case of webapp (.war), the beans.xml file has to be located in the WEB-INF folder !

Comment: Which tutorial did you read about the ManagedBean annotation? Each tutorial I  have seen does not do this. Even the original 'oracle' tutorial https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced004.html states to do what is done in the other answer (or add stateless like you did)

Comment: That's the problem of tutorials. They give some examples but do not clearly explain the principles. If you want to inject beans into a bean, your bean has to become "cdi-aware". A JAX-RS bean (resource) is by default not a CDI bean, you have to add annotation to allow injection. You have plenty of different possible annotations (Stateless, Stateful, Singleton, RequestScoped, ApplicationScoped, etc..) and one of these (the most basic actually) is javax.annotation.ManagedBean.

Comment: Please read the doc (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/ManagedBean.html): "the ManagedBean annotation marks a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) as a ManagedBean. A ManagedBean supports a small set of basic services such as resource injection".